# Do I have to use instanceof or is there any polymorphic solution?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

My assignment is to create a simple Appointment `superclass` with three ( Daily, OneTime , Monthly) `subclasses`.

then I need to ask user to enter different appointments and store them in an `ArrayList` through a method called `add`. user should select the type of the appointment too.

I am new to polymorphism and try to find a polymorphic solution instead of using `instanceof` Operator.

Is it possible in my case?

Could you help me to have a better understanding of `polymorphism` please?

Comment: For what exactly do you need `instanceof`? It is generally a not so good idea to use `instanceof`. If you tell us a little bit more about what you are trying to check, we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need the instanceof operator at all. Make an Appointment class and make each time (Daily, OneTime, Monthly) extend appointment so they can use it's variables and methods.

Example:

```
public Daily extends Appointment
```

From there you should be able to make a main class to test what you've made and store the values in an ArrayList. For example:

```
List<Appointment> arrayList = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
arrayList.add("supply subclass object that you've created here");
```

Continue to add until all subclasses have been added to your appointment arraylist. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the Java Tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to store/add all the subtypes in an `ArrayList` , then you can choose the type parameter (the `Class` type within '<' and '>') as the superclass ie `Appointment`. So you can do `List<Appointment> apps = new ArrayList<Appointment>();`

now you can store all the subtypes as follows :-

`apps.add(new Daily());
 apps.add(new OneTime());
 apps.add(new Monthly());`

If you want to get any object from this `ArrayList` you can also assign it in a refrence variable  of parent type ie `Appointment` as `Appointment a = apps.get(0);`

And finally if you want to call any overriden method on this `a` variable
it will automatically call the overriden method of the actual subtype, by the property of `Polymorphism`.

Also if you want to somewhere specifically check the class of `Appointment` reference variable you can use `getClass()` method and compare it with the subclaases. So i am not sure why & where you want to use `instanceof`. Hope this might clear your queries a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it would be even better if you use **interfaces**.
Interface specifies contract (i.e. what should the class be and what should it be able to do), and helps to avoid problems related 
to inheritance e.g. dependency on superclass methods.
And still lets you inherit other classes.
Overall - interfaces are more flexible.

I would code:

```
public Daily implements Appointment
```

and then just as **@unsensibled**  mentioned:

```
List<Appointment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Appointment daily = new Daily();
arrayList.add(daily);
```